# Unable to start MySQL server - Control process exited with error code

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-error-1064

My mysql server is not starting after stopping it

Command using:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Error :

> Restarting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.serviceJob for mysql.service
> failed because the control process exited with error code.

Checked status using `systemctl status mysql.service` and `journalctl -xe`, did not get any help.

Error log:

-

> ```
> 2020-06-23T00:11:48.882919Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use
> ```
>
> --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
>
> ```
> 2020-06-23T00:11:48.883135Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /u1/mysql/sad-swh.lower-test
>
> 2020-06-23T00:11:48.883185Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.30-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) starting as process 28411 ...
>
> 2020-06-23T00:11:48.886131Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /u1/mysql/sad-swh.lower-test
>
> 2020-06-23T00:11:48.886148Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /u1/mysql/sad-swh.lower-test
>
> 2020-06-23T00:11:48.889591Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
>
> 2020-06-23T00:11:48.889612Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
>
> 2020-06-23T00:11:48.889616Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
>
> 2020-06-23T00:11:48.889620Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
>
> 2020-06-23T00:11:48.889623Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
>
> 2020-06-23T00:11:48.889627Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
>
> 2020-06-23T00:11:48.889890Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
>
> 2020-06-23T00:11:48.890022Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
>
> 2020-06-23T00:11:48.892207Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
>
> 2020-06-23T00:11:48.900818Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
>
> 2020-06-23T00:11:48.903535Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be
> ```
>
> changed. See the man page of setpriority().
>
> ```
> 2020-06-23T00:11:48.913543Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: The first innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' did not exist. A new tablespace will
> ```
>
> be created!
>
> ```
> 2020-06-23T00:11:48.913858Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
>
> 2020-06-23T00:11:48.913871Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory.
>
> 2020-06-23T00:11:48.913878Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
>
> 2020-06-23T00:11:48.913883Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory.
>
> 2020-06-23T00:11:48.913889Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile './ibdata1'
>
> 2020-06-23T00:11:48.913896Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to
> ```
>
> the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit
> innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the
> new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only
> wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any way.
> But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your
> precious data!
>
> ```
> 2020-06-23T00:11:48.913903Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: InnoDB Database creation was aborted with error Cannot open a file. You may need to
> ```
>
> delete the ibdata1 file before trying to start up again.
>
> ```
> 2020-06-23T00:11:49.514733Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
>
> 2020-06-23T00:11:49.514763Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
>
> 2020-06-23T00:11:49.514773Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
>
> 2020-06-23T00:11:49.514779Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
>
> 2020-06-23T00:11:49.514817Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
>
> 2020-06-23T00:11:49.514889Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
>
> 2020-06-23T00:11:49.515486Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
> ```

```
 ● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service;
 enabled;
 vendor preset: enabled) Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-06-22 16:07:36 CST;
 9min ago Process: 26756 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE) Process: 26737 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS) Main PID: 18936 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Comment: Here is the status - ● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-06-22 16:07:36 CST; 9min ago
  Process: 26756 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 26737 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 18936 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Comment: you should add to your question the mysql error log

Comment: the log is added @nbk

Comment: you cut out the good parts, don't leave nothing out, so we can't see what os the problem

Comment: it say clearly Cannot open datafile './ibdata1'  so mysql has nit thecorect right i he data directory, so set the rights right and evrything should run. as yo an see reading the error log it tells you everything you need to do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mysql server stopped unexpectedly on my new on Ubuntu 18.04 instance, and getting same error while trying to start.

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

When running the command `systemctl status mysql.service`

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-08-29 17:11:53 UTC; 11s ago
  Process: 3124 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2557 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 29 17:11:53 ip-172-26-10-122 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 29 17:11:53 ip-172-26-10-122 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 29 17:11:53 ip-172-26-10-122 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

**After struggling almost 6 hours searching over the internet finally got the solution.**

```
sudo chmod -R u+rwx /etc/mysql/
sudo chown -R mysql.mysql /etc/mysql/
```

Answer (score 1):

my issue was by executing the following commands:

chown mysql:adm /var/log/mysql/error.log

chown mysql:adm /var/log/mysql

chown root:syslog /var/log

chown root:root /var

chmod 0640 /var/log/mysql/error.log

chmod 0750 /var/log/mysql

chmod 0775 /var/log

chmod 0755 /var

systemctl status mysql.service

Answer (score 1):

Regards to Everyone.

Thanks for all your messages which were quite usefull for me, but the root cause in my case was that /var filesystem was full (100% occupied), I just duplicate the size or physical partitions and I could restart "mysql" RDBMS. If you can´t increase /var filesystem´s size, then evaluate which log files are the biggest and what you can "touch" to eliminate its contents and recreate it with no data inside at all (just the log file name). I hope this is som piece of help for you as it was for me

CE

Answer (score 0):

**Solved the issue with these commands**

```
sudo chmod a+rwx mysql /location
sudo chown mysql.mysql /location
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was the RAM.

> But if you are on a 512MB droplet running both git and a full
> WordPress, then it is expected to run out of RAM. It’s actually quite
> difficult to run WordPress on 512MB.
>
> I would generally say that WordPress needs 1GB RAM minimum in
> production. You might be able to run on 512MB, but if just a couple of
> people visit your site at the same time and WordPress is checking for
> updates, then you can easily run out of RAM.

[Source](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/mysql-stopped-and-it-can-t-be-restart?comment=59092)