# Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code

Tags: mysql

I've installed MySQL-server, enabled the port 3306 in the firewall then executed
`sudo systemctl restart mysql`, I'm getting error:-

`Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

After looking into the `systemctl status mysql.service` I got the log:-

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2021-08-15 20:11:40 PDT; 132ms ago
    Process: 2801384 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 2801392 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 2801392 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"
      Error: 99 (Cannot assign requested address)
```

Then I fixed the error for line     `Process: 2801392 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)`, with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62524355/unable-to-start-mysql-server-control-process-exited-with-error-code) stackoverflow answer. Then I again executed

`systemctl status mysql.service` I got for sometime the log:-

```
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (start) since Sun 2021-08-15 20:11:38 PDT; 541ms ago
    Process: 2801384 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 2801392 (mysqld)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"
      Tasks: 13 (limit: 309219)
     Memory: 248.2M
     CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
             └─2801392 /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

But after a few seconds, the log again started showing the previous one(code=exited, status=1/FAILURE).

Also the log for `journalctl -xe`:-

```
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit mysql.service has exited.
--
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Aug 15 20:16:13 si-gpu1.linkgrid.com systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- The unit mysql.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 15 20:16:13 si-gpu1.linkgrid.com systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit mysql.service has finished with a failure.
--
-- The job identifier is 5422093 and the job result is failed.
Aug 15 20:16:14 si-gpu1.linkgrid.com systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 199.
-- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Automatic restarting of the unit mysql.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Aug 15 20:16:14 si-gpu1.linkgrid.com systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished.
--
-- The job identifier is 5422193 and the job result is done.
Aug 15 20:16:14 si-gpu1.linkgrid.com systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit mysql.service has begun execution.
```

Which after following [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/981403/failed-to-start-mysql-community-server) gives the log:-

```
 mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 628.
-- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Automatic restarting of the unit mysql.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Aug 15 20:35:38 si-gpu1.linkgrid.com systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished.
--
-- The job identifier is 5465197 and the job result is done.
Aug 15 20:35:38 si-gpu1.linkgrid.com sshd[2830014]: Invalid user support from 122.53.65.209 port 63290
Aug 15 20:35:38 si-gpu1.linkgrid.com systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit mysql.service has begun execution.
```

I've done multiple thing(Involved re-installing as well) which is mentioned over net. But nothing worked. "I'm only getting server startup in progress."

Comment: Did you ever find the reason for this? Facing the same problem after a failed upgrade from Ubuntu 16 to 20.

Answer (score 1):

Try these commands:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop

service mysql stop

killall -KILL mysql mysqld_safe mysqld

/etc/init.d/mysql start

service mysql start
```